# Random (?) ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have looked at some of the other questions covering this topic, but I don't see this particular issue anywhere. I have a test that clicks on a Web Element. I have tried referencing it by ID and by XPath, and waiting for it to become visible using `wait.until()`.

Sometimes it seems to work fine, but other times I get `ElementNotVisibleException`. (Actually, since I added the `wait.until()`, I get `TimeoutException`, but if I removed that, it would throw `ElementNotVisibleException`.) That is, I can run the test once and it will be able to click the element and proceed to completion. Other times, I get the exception. The issue is not whether I get one exception or the other, the issue is getting the exception sometimes, but other times being able to reference the element without any exception at all.

I have not made any changes that I am aware of. The page appears to load quickly and correctly every time. There are no server issues I am aware of. Roughly about half the time it throws the exception, and the other half it can reference the element without any problems.

Is this likely to perhaps be more of a problem with the underlying web site code than with Selenium? I have checked the computed CSS values manually and they appear to indicate that the element should be visible.

Comment: Well the reason for the TimeoutException is because the wait.until() function throws it because the element does not become visible that's why you see one or the other. If after the page loads you run a separate test to see if Selenium thinks the element is visible what do you get?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what my issue is. I will try running a separate test to drill-down on whether it's visible from Selenium's perspective -- thank you for that idea.

Comment: Are you sure each time the element is visible?

Have you tried both of following?

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

Answer (score -4):

The main problem is loading the page. If page loading is delayed then the web elements are not found at the time that exception is thrown.

To resolve above issue use

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds); method.
```

Comment: It might be delayed sometimes, but I already have a WebDriverWait that is set to wait for the element for 6 minutes.